# AWS Lightsail 'Exception occurred processing WSGI script'

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, apache, deployment, amazon-lightsail

I followed the amazon tutorial EXACTLY for deploying a Django app on lightsail: [Deploy Django-based application
onto Amazon Lightsail](https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/hands-on/deploy-python-application/).

But when I visit my IP address (`http://52.41.70.195/`) I get Internal server error. When I check the apache error logs I see these errors:

```
Failed to parse Python script file '/opt/bitnami/projects/Django-E -Commerce/perfectcushion/wsgi.py'. 

Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/opt/bitnami/projects/Django-E-Commerce/perfectcushion/wsgi.py'.
```

My wsgi.py file looks like the one amazon provides:

```py
import os
import sys
sys.path.append('/opt/bitnami/projects/Django-E-Commerce’)
os.environ.setdefault("PYTHON_EGG_CACHE", "/opt/bitnami/projects/Django-E-Commerce/egg_cache")
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", “Django-E-Commerce.settings")
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Could you append the complete error trace please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have experienced the same issue. I solved it by following Bitnami documentation too. [check it here](https://docs.bitnami.com/ibm/infrastructure/django/get-started/deploy-django-project/)

You have to configure your Virtual Host